# Xpath expression to select elements relative to current node

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using Selenium Webdriver in Python. I want to iterate through and count the number of visible input elements with `type="text"` or `type="password"` or `type="button"`. I want to do it by first extracting the input tags and then iterating through them.

Here is what I've tried -

```
Text_Xpath2 = "./[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"
Pass_Xpath2 = "./[@type='password']"
Button_Xpath2 = "./[@type='button' or @type='submit']"

or 

Text_Xpath2 = "[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"
Pass_Xpath2 = "[@type='password']"
Button_Xpath2 = "[@type='button' or @type='submit']"


inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input')

for input in inputs:
    if input.is_displayed():
        text_fields = input.find_element_by_xpath(Text_Xpath2)
        pass_fields = input.find_element_by_xpath(Pass_Xpath2)
        buttons = input.find_element_by_xpath(Button_Xpath2)
```

I always get this error -

> The string './[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']' is
>   not a valid XPath expression.

Can somebody point out whats the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the tag, for example `<div>`

```
".//div[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"
```

Or any tag

```
".//*[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"
```

In you case you don't need it, `.` in `xpath` is used to locate descendant element of the current element, not to relocate the same element again. Try

```
inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="text" or @type="email" or @type="username"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it throws this error - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./input[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"}

Comment: More info - I am trying to achieve this on - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/management/signin

Comment: I also tried this (.//input[...]) but same error - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='username']"}

Comment: I had that in mind but I assumed that there is no need to use the input tag again as we have already selected all the input elements through inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input'). Thanks again.